# Help with calculating the sum of series

Tags: calculus

I need help to calculate the following sum:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n+1}  x^{n}$$
I managed to develop it to:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n} -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} x^{n}$$

But now I'm not sure what to do with the right one. The left on is easy.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Obviously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), $|x|<1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n} -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} x^{n}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n} -\dfrac 1x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} x^{n+1}$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n} +\dfrac 1x (\log (1-x)+x)$$

$$=\dfrac 1{1-x}-1 +\dfrac 1x (\log (1-x)+x)$$

$$=\dfrac 1{1-x} +\dfrac x{\log (1-x)}$$ using the [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for $\log (1-x)$.

Comment: I think you need to have $\frac{1}{1-x}-1$, as the geometric series starts with $n=1$ and not $n=0$.

Comment: Starting $n=1$, the formula is $\;\dfrac x{1-x}$. Furthermore, you might want to develop the second term, then simplify with the first one.

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $\dfrac{x^n}{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{x}\cdot \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, and you can find $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ by differentiation-then-integration-term-by-term method.

Comment: thank you i think i got it!